# how simplify the [ngClass] in a template

Tags: angular

The [ngClass] in this template way too long. Is there a simple way to do it?  Thank you.

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="ThisConsult.Status">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header [ngClass]="'headerStyle'">Status</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    <div [ngClass]="{'seahawk': element.ThisConsult.Status==='PENDING', 'blue': element.ThisConsult.Status==='ACTIVE',
            'blackOnWhite': element.ThisConsult.Status==='DISCONTINUED', 'grayOnWhite': element.ThisConsult.Status=='COMPLETE',
            'bloody': element.ThisConsult.Status==='CANCELLED'}">
      {{element.ThisConsult.Status}}
    </div>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Merge the css to a parent class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use object as dictionary:

**component.ts**

```ts
class SomeComponent {
  statuses = {
    PENDING: 'seahawk',
    ACTIVE: 'blue',
    DISCONTINUED: 'blackOnWhite',
    COMPLETE: 'grayOnWhite',
    CANCELLED: 'bloody'
  }
  ...
```

**template.html**

```html
[ngClass]="statuses[element.ThisConsult.Status]"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function on your Component to call on your template to avoid long list of conditions on your ngClass

Example:

**UserComponent**

```
@Component({...})
export class UserComponent {

    constructor() {}

    assignClassByStatus(element: any): string {
        const classes = [
            { name: 'seahawk', type: 'PENDING' },
            { name: 'blue', type: 'ACTIVE' },
            { name: 'blackOnWhite', type: 'COMPLETE' },
            { name: 'grayOnWhite', type: 'DISCONTINUED' },
            { name: 'bloody', type: 'CANCELLED' },
        ];

        const className = classes.find(({ type }) => type === element).name;

        return className;
    }

}
```

**User Template**

```
...

<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
   <div [ngClass]="assignClassByStatus(element)">{{element.ThisConsult.Status}}</div>
</td>
```